# Compare two columns and return value from third column

Tags: excel, vlookup

`Column 1` is my source data column, `Column 2` and `3` are my reference list. What I want is to index or match the rules from `Column 2 + Column 3` and compare with `Column 1` and return the matched rule value to the result column within same row.

[image]

Please note that all the values are string (text) and no numbers involved.

Comment: why is test 2 result 2 and not 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but along the lines of what user1917229 suggested, can you simply check if your source column is empty, and if not, return the first value in the first column and the column 3 value in the second (per your update)? For example, in cell `D2` (and dragged down):

```
=IF(A2="", "", A2)
```

And `E2`:

```
=IF(A2="", "", VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$C$14,2,FALSE))
```

Note that I'm not sure what you wanted with the `+`, so this just literally returns it - if this isn't what you want, hopefully the concept makes sense and can be adjusted.

[image]

Comment: Hi RocketDonkey, very appreciated your last answer. So, if I want to put those two values in two columns, how should I do it? I mean Result 1 just show Test 1~Test 9, and result two column show that C1~C10.

Comment: @James0419 Just updated - is that closer to what you're looking for? Basic idea is to split the formula into two pieces, each one in a column.

Comment: @James0419 Ha, no problem, likewise :)

Answer (score 0):

[VLookUp](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) may be what you want.

```
 =VLOOKUP(A3,$B$3:$C$12,2,TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I guess I pasted the wrong photo for that. I updated.

Comment: Thanks user1917229, I guess I didn't explain the issue very well at the first. I updated it now.